# How to make modal scroll with main page

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal with the contents taller than the browser height, as a result I have some contents which cannot be displayed. (seems like the modal position is fixed and cannot be scrolled as a whole)

[image]

How can I make the modal scrollable with the main page so that I can actually view the contents below?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you could do is set the modal's CSS `position` to absolute instead of fixed.

To do this, just get the class name of the modal or ID like this and set it to `absolute`:

```
.modal {
position: absolute !important;
}
```

Or, even better, edit the main CSS for your modal (if you can) and change the `position` from `fixed` to `absolute`.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hUNZs/

Comment: I've found also another nice and simple solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34897879/964919

Answer (score 2):

I've tried `<div class="modal myModal"></div>`

CSS

```
.myModal {
      overflow: auto !important; 
      height: 300px; //set a height to a modal so it wont overlapped when the body tag's height is smaller than the modal
}
```

Comment: oops I forgot to read the "cannot be scrolled as a whole" part. sorry

Comment: This appears to be the opposite of what he's looking for.

Comment: I've edited my answer... I also had this problem, and I concluded that when the body's height is taller than the modal's height the modal is scrollable (just an observation though)