# How to scroll the page when a modal dialog is longer than the screen?

Tags: css, scroll

I have a modal dialog in my app which can get quite long in the y direction. This introduces a problem whereby some of the content of the dialog is hidden off the bottom of the page.

[image]

I would like the window scrollbar to scroll the dialog when it is displayed and too long to fit on the screen but leave the main body in place behind the modal. If you use [Trello](http://trello.com) then you know what I'm going for.

Is this possible without using JavaScript to control the scrollbar?

Here is the CSS I have applied to my modal and dialog so far:

```
body.blocked {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-screen {
  background: #717174;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 50;
}

.dialog {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 12px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0, 0, 8px, #111;
}
```

Comment: try overflow:auto or overflow:scroll in the dialog...

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Try:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It will arrange your modal and then give it an vertical scroll

Comment: why do we have to use 210px? Is there any particular reason behind it?

Comment: you can change it according to your need but make sure it has to be configured with  calc(100vh - xxxxxx); whole formula

Comment: @ShellZero, it's sum of: modal header, modal footer, top and bottom space between modal and window borders.

Comment: Is there solution without hardcoding footer and header height?

Comment: If you want it to feel as a regular scroll on iOS you'd want to add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; as well, because Mobile Safari treats overflow scrolling differently than regular page scrolling unless it's specifically told not to.

Answer (score 58):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
max-height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
```

**EDIT**: I now use the same method currently used on Twitter where the modal acts sort of like a separate page on top of the current content and the content behind the modal does not move as you scroll.

In essence it is this:

```
var scrollBarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.body.offsetWidth;
$('body').css({
  marginRight: scrollBarWidth,
  overflow: 'hidden'
});
$modal.show();
```

With this CSS on the modal:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0x0049/koodkcng/
Pure JS version (IE9+): https://jsfiddle.net/0x0049/koodkcng/1/

This works no matter the height or width of the page or modal dialog, allows scrolling no matter where your mouse/finger is, doesn't have the jarring jump some solutions have that disable scroll on the main content, and looks great too.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the OP. How to scroll the PAGE when the modal is too long. it doesn't actually scroll the page but it creates the illusion of scrolling the page which fits the use case of not wanting to take up vertical space with bottom margin on the screen. all other solutions including the accepted answer have that problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that addresses the question, as @ynot said.

Answer (score 15):

Change `position`

```
position:fixed;
overflow: hidden;
```

to

```
position:absolute;
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. It's like the window doesn't realise that the dialog has height.

Comment: The problem is `position: fixed;` Could it be change into absolute or else?

Comment: If I do that I run into another problem. If the user is already scrolled way down the page when they open the dialog, it will appear at the very top of the page, out of shot of the current window.

Comment: This worked for me - both in normal modals and when I had a modal in a modal (which Bootstrap says [overlapping modals are not supported... it requires custom code](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)).

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to the OP, because you are scrolling the page, not scrolling the modal

Answer (score 6):

Here is my demo of modal window that auto-resize to its content and starts scrolling when it does not fit the window.

[Modal window demo](http://demo.chobits.ch/CSS3/modal.html) (see comments in the HTML source code)

**All done only with HTML and CSS** - no JS required to display and resize the modal window <strike>(but you still need it to display the window of course</strike> - in new version you don't need JS at all).

Update (more demos):

- [Modal window aligned to top](http://demo.chobits.ch/css3/modal/top.html)
- [Centered Modal window](http://demo.chobits.ch/css3/modal/center.html)
- [Old demo that use Javascript](http://demo.chobits.ch/css3/modal/js.html)

The point is to have outer and inner DIVs where the outer one defines the fixed position and the inner creates the scrolling. *(In the demo there are actually more DIVs to make them look like an actual modal window.)*

```
        #modal {
            position: fixed;
            transform: translate(0,0);
            width: auto; left: 0; right: 0;
            height: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;
            z-index: 990; /* display above everything else */
            padding: 20px; /* create padding for inner window - page under modal window will be still visible */
        }

        #modal .outer {
            box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        #modal .inner {
            box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;       /* allow to fit content (if smaller)... */
            max-height: 100%;   /* ... but make sure it does not overflow browser window */

            /* allow vertical scrolling if required */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

            /* definition of modal window layout */
            background: #ffffff;
            border: 2px solid #222222;
            border-radius: 16px; /* some nice (modern) round corners */
            padding: 16px;       /* make sure inner elements does not overflow round corners */
        }
```

Comment: Can you lock the page once the popup is open to prevent scrolling? If user has the mouse outside the popup, he will scroll the page instead of popup and once that happens and he moves over popup he will get the popup and the page scrolling. Thanks

Comment: @Adyyda You can stop scrolling by wrapping the page in a DIV with `overflow:hidden` and settings its size to the same as the page and its `margin-top` to negative of its `scroll-top`.

Comment: This was a good and appropriate solution Radek - responsive, cross browser, simply done using CSS. Saved me some time, thanks

Comment: @RadekPech how is that any different than doing `html,body{ overflow:hidden }`?

Comment: @StevenVachon In a page as simple as the demo and a limited number of supported browsers there may not be any difference. But in a more complex page or in a specific browser setting `html,body{ overflow:hidden }` just may not work as expected. So it may look like an _overkill_ but _better safe than sorry_.

Answer (score 4):

simple way you can do this by adding this css
So, you just added this to CSS:

```
.modal-body {
position: relative;
padding: 20px;
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and it's working!

Answer (score 2):

fixed positioning alone should have fixed that problem but another good workaround  to avoid this issue is to place your modal divs or elements at the bottom of the page not within your sites layout. Most modal plugins give their modal positioning absolute to allow the user keep main page scrolling.

```
<html>
        <body>
        <!-- Put all your page layouts and elements


        <!-- Let the last element be the modal elemment  -->
        <div id="myModals">
        ...
        </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here.. Works perfectly for me

```
.modal-body { 
    max-height:500px; 
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`position:fixed` implies that, well, the modal window will remain fixed relative to the viewpoint. I agree with your assessment that it's appropriate in this scenario, with that in mind why don'y you add a scrollbar to the modal window itself?

If so, correct `max-height` and `overflow` properties should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had had to make changes to the content of the page behind the modal screen to ensure that it never got long enough to scroll the page.

Once I did that, the problems I encountered when applying `position: absolute` to the dialog were resolved as the user could no longer scroll down the page.

Comment: you just have skipped your issue

Comment: both question and answered post by you and you also accept your answer, then why you post question here?

Comment: @Thiyagu that is considered OK. If the questioner finds the solution they themselves should post an answer. They are also free to accept whichever answer helped them. The end goal is to help the community as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Window Page Scrollbar clickable when Modal is open

This one works for me. Pure CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">

body.modal-open {
padding-right: 17px !important;
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
margin-right: 16px; 

</style>
```

Try it and let me know

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to add my pure CSS answer to this problem of modals with dynamic width and height. The following code also works with the following requirements:

1. Place modal in center of screen
2. If modal is higher than viewport, scroll dimmer (not modal content)

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__content">
        (Long) Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS/LESS:

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: @qquad;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: @zindex-modal;

    &__content {
        width: 900px;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 90%;
        padding: @quad;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
}
```

This way the modal is always within the viewport. The width and height of the modal are as flexible as you like. I removed my close icon from this for simplicity.