# How to add scroll into react-bootstrap Modal.Body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I'm using [react-bootstrap modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).

How can I make only body to scroll and not all the page?

```
  <Modal.Dialog>
    <Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>

    <Modal.Body>One fine body...</Modal.Body>

    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button>Close</Button>
      <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal.Dialog>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can add `scrollable` to the `Modal`:

```
<Modal scrollable={true}>
</Modal>
```

You can get details from the [`Modal` docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#modals)

Comment: Since this post has already accepted an answer, it's preferred to add a comment or make an edition for it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation referral. This could be implemented on new versions. It should do the job.

Answer (score 40):

Thanks to [Amit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476632/how-to-scroll-the-page-when-a-modal-dialog-is-longer-than-the-screen).

The first solution using only styles would be the following:

```
  <Modal.Dialog>
    <Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>

    <Modal.Body style={{
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 210px)',
      overflowY: 'auto'
     }}
    >
     One fine body...
    </Modal.Body>

    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button>Close</Button>
      <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal.Dialog>
```

There is a new way to implement that behavior using the `react-bootstrap` itself:

```html
<Modal
  scrollable={true}
  ....
>
  ....
</Modal>
```

[Modal Documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#modals)

Comment: React recommended changing `max-height` to `maxHeight` and `overflow-y` to `overflowY`

Comment: I have a button that slightly overflows on the X, and now the overflow on the horizontal is over-proportioned. overflowX: auto doesn't seem to scale this down. How would you handle this?

Comment: If the X is overflowing there would be some child that is pushing the width. You can also set the `overflow-x: none` if it's necessary.

Comment: The biggest issue ive found with this is that using "-210px" makes it's height change depending on screen size, which kind of defeats the responsive intention of bootstrap