# Angular Modal I want to be scrollable but not when click dragging certain div

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I have an Ionic app that utilizes AngularJS.  In it, there's a modal popup that can sometimes be larger than the viewable area..

so we added `overflow: hidden` to it's css class..

BUT, there's a feature to this modal where we draw lines on the map when users click and drag.  The lines draw fine (it's using canvas) and are all contained within a `<div>` element.

Is there a way to simply disable click-drag when a click starts inside this `<div>` tag?

update:  Still need help.. essentially I've got a modal that was exhibiting the same behavior as this [How to make modal scroll with main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060541/how-to-make-modal-scroll-with-main-page)

now I have

```
<ion-modal-view class="my-modal">
  <ion-content style="position:absolute">
      <div class="row main-wrapper">
          <div class="left-panel-wrapper {{setSize}} col-25" >
              <div ng-show="!showMyPlans || loading" class="left-panel {{setSize}} item-animate">
                  <h3>My Plan Templates</h3>
                  <p>Select a template from the left or select to start from scratch.</p>
                  <ion-content scroll='true' class="left-panel-template">
                      <div ng-repeat="template in templates" ng-class-even="'float-right'" ng-class-odd="'float-left'">
                          <div class="usemouse graph-bg templates-bg {{setSize}}">
                              <div data-drag="true" ng-model="templates" jqyoui-draggable="{index:{{$index}}, placeholder: 'keep', deepCopy: true}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone', containment: '.my-modal'}">
                                  <svg ng-style="{'position': 'absolute', 'height': '{{rawSmallSize}}px', 'width': '{{rawSmallSize}}px'}" ng-repeat="line in template.lines">
                                      <line ng-attr-x1="{{line.x1*smscale}}" ng-attr-y1="{{line.y1*smscale}}" ng-attr-x2="{{line.x2*smscale}}" ng-attr-y2="{{line.y2*smscale}}"></line>
                                  </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div ng-show="template.lines.length == 0" class="usemouse graph-bg templates-bg {{setSize}} templates-blank text-center" style="margin-top:0" on-tap="newBlankPlan();">
                                  <h6  style="margin-top:0" >Blank</h6>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </ion-content>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this wiggle issue by removing all the padding from the modal..

```
<ion-content style="position:absolute; padding-top:0">
    <div class="row main-wrapper">
        <div class="left-panel-wrapper {{setSize}} col-25" >
```